# Illustrator: Vector Layers Disappearing

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I've sent a CS6 AI file to someone else to add a vector layer, in addition to an existing vector layer, with a raster layer as a reference.

They're using CC, and when they send it back (both AI and PDF) there's just a clip group confined to the artboard, which only contains part of the raster layer (I was reusing an old AI file because the swatches matched and hadn't set it up yet). I can disable the clipping mask and see the whole raster layer, but both vector layers are missing.

When I select the file in the File Open dialog, I can see that both vector layers are in place and the full raster layer is visible.

Is there a way I can get the vector layers to work?

Comment: Is the problem happening when the CC people open the file or when they send it back to you? Where is it not working? It's not exactly clear to me. Either way have you tried sending it in a different format?

Comment: The vector layer they've added in CC doesn't show up when I open the result in CS6.

Answer (score 2):

Tell the person using CC to back-save to CS6 format....

Or upgrade to CC so you are both using the same version.

Illustrator files are not inherently backwards compatible. If a file needs compatibility with a legacy version, that needs to be specifically indicated in the Save As process. In addition, since feature sets vary, it is possible that some artwork gets expanded and flattened when moving to a legacy format.

If you get a version warning when opening the file, the file has *not* been saved to the legacy version you need. Even if the file *still* opens in spite of the version warning, you can generally assume some artwork is missing due to versioning.

Comment: I did specify to make it CS6 compatible, and it does open (often when receiving AI/EPS files I get an error that it's newer and can't be opened at all). It's also not flattened, the layers just aren't there at all...but they do show up in the preview, so Illustrator CS6 can presumably see them?

Comment: Are you stating you **do** get the version warning? That would indicate it's *not* a CS6 file. And the preview doesn't really mean anything. That's handled by the OS more than anything (Showing the preview of the PDF portion of an AI file)